# Как с помощью fori пройтись по HashMap?

Tags: java

Вот с помощью fore понятно

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = createMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair: map.entrySet())
    {
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
    }
```

а как это переделать чтоб классический цикл работал?

```
for(i = 0; o i < map.size(); i++){
// что тут?
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как-то так. Но здесь создается лишний List, поэтому если вам просто нужен индекс, то добавьте соот. переменную и инкрементируйте ее в цикле.

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    String key = keys.get(i);
    String value = map.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(i + " " + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());

      ++i; //iterate
}
```

или

```
  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
  for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
      if(iterator.hasNext()) {
          Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
          System.out.println(i + " " + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
      } else break;
  }
```